# Upload Images to Dropbox from Android showing null Pointer exception

Tags: android

Iam Uploading  the Images to Dropbox account from my android app.

while Uploading Images to Dropbox Not working.

It means Image Not Reaching properly to Dropbox(Some Times showing null pointer exception). How to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

According [official Dropbox developer documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/android) user should be signed in. User could not signing in only if he has Dropbox app installed on his device and signed in there.